# Populate form with localStorage

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery-mobile, local-storage

I'm building a webapp where I have a settings panel. I have a code that saves data from form to localStorage, but how could I make it populate the form automatically on pageload if there is some data saved to localStorage?

This is my code for the form:

```
<label for="serveri"> Server: </label> 
<input type='text' name="server" id="saveServer"/> 
<button onclick="save_data()" type="button" value="Save" id="Save" data-theme="a">Save</button> 

<script> function save_data()
{ var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
localStorage.setItem("server", input.value); 
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("server"); } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is add a `ready` method to load the data.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(input[name=server]).val(localStorage.getItem("server"));
});
```

Or non-[JQuery](http://jquery.com) answer.

```
function save_data() {
  // Save functionality here...
}

function load_data() {
  var input = document.getElementById("saveServer");
  input.value = localStorage.getItem("server");
}

load_data();
```

Just make sure your `form` exists before any of the JavaScript to populate it is executed.

Here is a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/hn78X/1/).

Comment: Could I theoretically just save the form in its entirety then set the value of the form as a whole to the form I saved in localstorage?

Comment: @DevinPrejean You could do `localStorage.setItem('Form') = $(form).html();`, then load the html back in. This may have unexpected downsides though. A better approach would probably be to scan the form for input names and values, then save them to a Key-Value object which would then be saved to localstorage with JSON.